# Run shell script before running maven test

Tags: maven, unit-testing, maven-3

Is there a way that I can run a bash/shell script ONLY before invoking unit tests. For instance, when I hit `mvn test`, I like the shell script to be executed before actually running the tests.

Thanks for your inputs.

Regards,
Vivek Ragunathan

Comment: Isn't that you can achieve actually in BeforeClass/BeforeMethod ?

Comment: @MonisMajeed actually i can't. The script has to be executed to set up a lot of things for the test to run correctly.

Comment: That means you don't have unit tests you have integration tests which should be handled with maven-failsave-plugin furthermore what kind of setup things should be done with a script which can't be done using java code?

Comment: @khmarbaiseThanks I am going to try maven-failsafe-plugin. From the look of it, I think this is what I need. Why can't I use Java code (@Before etc.)? Couple of reasons. Setting up environment involves loading data from remote server, environment variables etc. "that is mandatory for all of the tests". I am planning to run the tests in parallel. In that case, it would require some tests to run first before the other. Hope that makes sense.